Visual Studio is skipping some code when debugging after repair
After repairing my Visual Studio 2019, it executes some of the code and skips over others. I am thinking this behavior is caused by one or more Option settings. Can someone please help with this?
Here is the method where this occurs:
Dim FName As String = ""
With MainMenu.OpenFileDialog1
    .DefaultExt = "xlsx"
    .Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
    .InitialDirectory = My.Settings.XLPath
    If .ShowDialog = DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    FName = .FileName
    My.Settings.XLPath = Replace(FName, .SafeFileName, "")
    My.Settings.Save()
End With
Dim Tbl As New DataTable
Dim ShtName As String = ""
Dim CN As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & FName & 
    ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""")
CN.Open()
Dim TblLst As DataTable = CN.GetSchema("Tables")
If TblLst.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    ShtName = TblLst.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString
End If
Dim ODBCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * From [" & ShtName & "]", CN)
Dim ADP As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(ODBCmd)
ADP.Fill(Tbl)
Debug.WriteLine("Rows in Tbl: " & Tbl.Rows.Count)
CN.Close()
For Each Col As DataColumn In Tbl.Columns
    Debug.WriteLine(Col.ColumnName)
Next

When it get to the line that fills the datatable Tbl, it does not execute that line and returns to the form that called this method.

Have you tried a clean and rebuild?  Is it a release build?

Also, what (if anything) do you have for error handling at various levels of the program?  Do you normally run with the exception settings break-on-throw or just break-on-unhandled?

Craig, I have tried a clean and rebuild both before and after deleting all files in the \bin\release folder. The configuration of the project properties is set to "Active (Release)". The Exception Settings is set to "break when thrown" for "C++", "Common Language Runtime", "Java", "Java Script Runtime", "Managed Debugging Assistants" and "Win32" exceptions. And thank you for your prompt response.
I'm also still getting error messages saying it cannot file "Operators.vb" after doing all the steps above.

@LarryStinson Does it work when set to debug instead of release?

Note that when debugging a release build, you won't always get the experience you expect due to optimization.  It can be instructive to look at the disassembly of the executing machine code.

Many thanks for your help, guys, yes it works when I switched to Debug. The only difference I see now is that before I did the repair, when I opened a project, debug took me directly to the first breakpoint, but now it starts debugging on the first code line of the opening form (the first code line in the project).
